# Node is not returning the correct JSON response

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an object here which I want to return as a response but before that I want to add a couple of fields to it. When I add fields and print the object, it prints the new object but when I send the response, I still get old object before editing.

```
let applications = await ApplicationHandler.getApplicationOverview(application_id); //I want to edit this one

if (applications == null) {
    applications = [];
}
for (let i = 0; i < applications.length; i++) {
    let cube_application_id = applications[i].id;
    let application_ratings = await Application_Rating.findAll({where: {cube_application_id: cube_application_id}});
    let application_ratings_personal = await Application_Rating.findAll({
        where: {
            cube_application_id: cube_application_id,
            user_id: req.user.id
        }
    });
    let total_user_rating = 0;
    for (let rating of application_ratings) {
        let average_user_rating = (rating.personality_rating + rating.qualification_rating + rating.motivation_rating) / 3;
        total_user_rating = total_user_rating + average_user_rating;
    }
    applications[i].average_rating = total_user_rating / application_ratings.length;
    applications[i].recommended = application_ratings_personal.recommended;

    if (i == applications.length - 1) {

        console.log(applications); // this prints with those 2 fields.

        let successRes = {
            status: 200,
            data: applications
        };

        return successRes; //however, this returns the one which I had in the first line.
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you aren't waiting to get out of the loop and use `if (i == applications.length - 1)` instead? I would also use `applications.map()` instead of a for loop, `map` provide the index as the second argument of the callback. If you print successRes before sending it, do you see the right data?

Comment: @DrakaSAN No reason, In fact it was outside, I did this just for testing purpose. Yes, If I print before sending I get correct data. Even if I print after sending, I get right data but I don't get right data in postman response.

Comment: If the function return the right data, then the problem is between this function and when the response is sent, can you share that part of the code? I'd guess the result of that function is not what you give to `res.send` or the equivalent in the framework you are using.